# Какие рекурентные сети можно применить для групп связанных данных?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Имеется набор размеченных данных с множеством признаков (a, b, c, d ... n). Набор разделен на группы с переменным количеством образцов, где образцы связанны между собой неизвестными нам зависимостями.

Необходимо посторить сеть, которая выведет эти зависимости в группах и обучится отдавать правильный результат. То есть, на результат образца дополнительно должны влиять признаки всех остальных образцов группы.

Количество образцов в группе переменное, по-этому нельзя это решить обычной FNN. Задача, вероятно, решается LSTM, где по аналогии с временным рядом сеть должна опираться не только на прошлые, но и на будущие данные. Есть ли какая-то разновидность рекурентных сетей покрывающая эту проблему? Или техники/приемы, которые помогут?

Comment: Попробуйте [bidirectional LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-bidirectional-lstm-sequence-classification-python-keras/)